# ggplot2 error "Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: bins"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `df` that I am tryint to plot with the `geom_histogram` function:

```
structure(list(dFormat = c("11M 50S", "13M 30S", "14M 20S", "14M 40S", 
"1M 10S", "1M 20S", "1M 40S", "1M 50S", "2M 10S", "2M 20S", "2M 30S", 
"2M 40S", "2M 50S", "3M 0S", "3M 10S", "3M 20S", "3M 30S", "3M 40S", 
"3M 50S", "4M 0S", "4M 10S", "4M 20S", "4M 30S", "4M 40S", "4M 50S", 
"5M 0S", "5M 10S", "5M 20S", "5M 30S", "5M 40S", "5M 50S", "6M 0S", 
"6M 10S", "6M 20S", "6M 30S", "6M 40S", "6M 50S", "7M 0S", "7M 10S", 
"7M 20S", "7M 30S", "7M 40S", "7M 50S", "8M 0S", "8M 10S", "8M 20S", 
"8M 30S", "8M 40S", "8M 50S", "9M 0S", "9M 10S", "9M 20S", "9M 30S"
), freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 20L, 22L, 47L, 39L, 82L, 66L, 121L, 107L, 162L, 
145L, 208L, 162L, 240L, 162L, 228L, 200L, 197L, 159L, 185L, 126L, 
157L, 113L, 123L, 73L, 61L, 49L, 33L, 23L, 18L, 11L, 16L, 5L, 
6L, 4L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("dFormat", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
-53L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to make a simple histogram with the following code but I get an error:

`ggplot(df, aes(x = df$dFormat, y = df$freq)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity",binwidth = 50)`

`Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad`

Looking at the documentation I see:

`Number of bins. Overridden by binwidth. Defaults to 30`

Using `binwidth` doesn't solve the problem.

Changing `geom_histogram` to `geom_bar` is of no help either.

`In addition: Warning message:`
geom_bar()`no longer has a`binwidth`parameter. Please use`geom_histogram()`instead.`

I saw a similar question here but it is of no use

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981366/r-ggplot-error-unknown-parameters-binwidth-bins-pad/38739865#38739865)

Maybe @hadley would know

Comment: I think you want `geom_bar` rather than `geom_histogram`. And don't use the $ inside `aes()`

Comment: You currently have a discrete x axis, which means histograms/`stat_bin` won't be useful.  Bins and so `binwidth` work with a continuous x axis for making frequency plots.  Maybe clarify what you the resulting plot should look like?  If you want some of the x levels to be combined you may have to calculate summaries outside of ggplot2.

Comment: Your data is already a statistical summary. In this case you should use `geom_bar` to show the results instead of `geom_histogram` because `geom_histogram` would calculate the frequency for you. `binwidth` is not a useful parameter for categorical variables. If you really need to use `geom_histogram`, try making your `dFormat` variable continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I think Richard Telford's answer is already complete. 
Here is what I believe , you are looking for:

```
df <- structure(list(dFormat = c("11M 50S", "13M 30S", "14M 20S", "14M 40S", 
 "1M 10S", "1M 20S", "1M 40S", "1M 50S", "2M 10S", "2M 20S", "2M 30S",
 "2M 40S", "2M 50S", "3M 0S", "3M 10S", "3M 20S", "3M 30S", "3M 40S",
 "3M 50S", "4M 0S", "4M 10S", "4M 20S", "4M 30S", "4M 40S", "4M 50S",
 "5M 0S", "5M 10S", "5M 20S", "5M 30S", "5M 40S", "5M 50S", "6M 0S",
 "6M 10S", "6M 20S", "6M 30S", "6M 40S", "6M 50S", "7M 0S", "7M 10S",
 "7M 20S", "7M 30S", "7M 40S", "7M 50S", "8M 0S", "8M 10S", "8M 20S",
 "8M 30S", "8M 40S", "8M 50S", "9M 0S", "9M 10S", "9M 20S", "9M 30S"
 ), freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
 2L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 20L, 22L, 47L, 39L, 82L, 66L, 121L, 107L, 162L, 
 145L, 208L, 162L, 240L, 162L, 228L, 200L, 197L, 159L, 185L, 126L,
 157L, 113L, 123L, 73L, 61L, 49L, 33L, 23L, 18L, 11L, 16L, 5L,
 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("dFormat", "freq"), row.names = c(NA,
 -53L), class = "data.frame")

 ggplot(df, aes(x=dFormat,y=freq))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Comment: If you're going to be supplying the `y` in `aes` (and a code golfer) you can use `geom_col()` which assumes `stat=identity`.

Answer (score 0):

Bins and binwidth work with a continuous x-axis for making frequency plots. What you actually desire are barplots proportional to the value of the variable `dFormat` which is not continuous! The problem you also came across is the overlapping axis labels. Use `barplot()` To plot then order the axis labels:

```r
attach(df)
barplot(freq,names.arg=dFormat,
        cex.names=0.6,las=2, # order Axis labels-
        col = "steelblue")
```

Output:
[image]

Another possibility is to turn the df into a matrix and do pass it to the barplot function. This will yield the same output as above:

```r
m <- t( matrix(df[,2],dimnames=df[1]) )
barplot(m,
        cex.names=0.6,las=2,
        col = "steelblue")
```

**NB:** While you cannot change the count of the number of observations in each bar you can change their size of the bar by the `scale`:

```r
barplot(m,
        cex.names=0.6,las=2,
        col = 'steelblue',
        space=5 #space between bars)
```

This increases the space between bars and in turn, reduces bar width.
Output:
[image]